# What are some plugins/modules/extensions/etc to achieve single-sign on between an ASP.NET MVC site and drupal and/or joomla?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drupal, joomla, single-sign-on

We are weighing out adding a CMS for adding some static content to an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 based web portal.  Users are authenticated using forms authentication currently.  We would like authenticated users to be able to visit the CMS-based content without having to sign-in again.

The content in the CMS system will most likely be public, and not restricted to logged-in users.  However, we want to know which users visited which areas of the CMS content for analytical purposes.  Thus, when someone logs into the main site, we want to "log them in" programmatically to the CMS site as well.

We have narrowed down our search for a CMS system to either Joomla or Drupal.  We've played with .NET-based CMS systems before (Orchard and .NETNuke) and got pretty frustrated.  We feel choosing a CMS driven by large, active development community and a [big market share](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_management/all) is the best choice.

How would you go about this?  I've searched for plugins/modules/extensions to both systems but haven't found any.  In Joomla, I was able to programmatically log in a user with the advice given [here](http://docs.joomla.org/API15%3aJApplication/login).  And I could foresee perhaps wrapping this in some secure, backend RESTful call made by the ASP.NET MVC application when the user logs in there.  Or writing my own plugin.

However, I obviously would like to find an existing plugin to achieve this.  Our decision to choose Joomla over Drupal (or vice versa) will most likely be driven by which of these platforms has such a plugin, and how stable it is.  Specific recommendations for either platform are welcome.

Comment: This looks like it's a [Recommendation Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) rather than a programming question, and therefore not germane to StackOverflow

Comment: I will revise my question in an attempt to fix that

Comment: Are you looking for a generic plugin that will work for anything or for something specific? JFusion does a lot, but from what I know mainly looks at other php applicatoins.   If all you want to do is log somene into the Joomla site you could make a small standalont application for that that would trigger the authentication events.